# pos argument to networkx.draw() not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I'm trying to generate images of subgraphs of a graph where nodes should appear in the same locations for both graphs.

Based on the [documentation for networkx.draw the "pos" argument](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw) to the draw function accepts a dictionary which specifies the positions of the nodes.  I see several examples where people use the pos argument similar to this pattern:

```
positions = networkx.spring_layout( GraphObject )
networkx.draw( GraphObject, positions )
```

However, when I try this I find that the positions is apparently ignored - or at least when I draw a graph and record the position of its nodes, and then use that dictionary as the pos argument for drawing a subgraph the corresponding nodes are not plotted in the same locations.

Here is a simple reproducer that demonstrates the problem.  I think what this code should do is create two .png files of two graphs "g" and "h."  The nodes "c" and "d" should be in the same position in the drawing of "h" as they are in "g" - however they are not.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import pylab

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_node( 'a' )
g.add_node( 'b' )
g.add_node( 'c' )
g.add_node( 'd' )
g.add_edge( 'a', 'b' )
g.add_edge( 'c', 'd' )

h = nx.Graph()
h.add_node( 'c' )
h.add_node( 'd' )

# Define the positions of a, b, c, d
positions = nx.spring_layout( g )

# Produce image of graph g with a, b, c, d and some edges.
nx.draw( g, positions )
plt.savefig( "g.png" )

# Clear the figure.
plt.clf()

# Produce image of graph h with two nodes c and d which should be in
# the same positions of those of graph g's nodes c and d.
nx.draw( h, positions )
plt.savefig( "h.png" )
```

Can anyone please suggest what I'm doing wrong, or how to generate images of subgraphs where the nodes are in the same location as that of the full graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tcaswell's tip as a starting point I found this worked for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_node( 'a' )
g.add_node( 'b' )
g.add_node( 'c' )
g.add_node( 'd' )
g.add_edge( 'a', 'b' )
g.add_edge( 'c', 'd' )

h = nx.Graph()
h.add_node( 'c' )
h.add_node( 'd' )

# Define the positions of a, b, c, d
positions = nx.spring_layout( g )

nx.draw( g, positions )

# Save the computed x and y dimensions for the entire drawing region of graph g
xlim = plt.gca().get_xlim()
ylim = plt.gca().get_ylim()

# Produce image of graph g with a, b, c, d and some edges.
plt.savefig( "g.png" )
#plt.show()

# Clear the figure.
plt.clf()

# Produce image of graph h with two nodes c and d which should be in
# the same positions of those of graph g's nodes c and d.
nx.draw( h, positions )

# Ensure the drawing area and proportions are the same as for graph g.
plt.axis( [ xlim[0], xlim[1], ylim[0], ylim[1] ] )

#plt.show()
plt.savefig( "h.png" )
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not that `networkx` is mis-behaving, it is that the x and y limits are different in the two figures

```
# Define the positions of a, b, c, d
positions = nx.spring_layout( g )
plt.figure()
# Produce image of graph g with a, b, c, d and some edges.
nx.draw( g, positions )
#plt.savefig( "g.png" )
_xlim = plt.gca().get_xlim() # grab the xlims
_ylim = plt.gca().get_ylim() # grab the ylims
# Clear the figure.
# plt.clf()
plt.figure()
# Produce image of graph h with two nodes c and d which should be in
# the same positions of those of graph g's nodes c and d.
nx.draw( h, positions )

plt.gca().set_xlim(_xlim) # set the xlims
plt.gca().set_ylim(_ylim) # set the ylims
# plt.savefig( "h.png" )
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking a look - but did you actually test the above code to see if it places nodes c and d at the same spot in both plots?  I have two problems when I run your code - first if I don't put back the plt.savefig lines nothing is output or displayed, to screen or elsewhere. 

If I put back the plt.savefig lines the nodes show up in different spots.

Comment: I removed the `savefig` lines because it is really obnoxious when people post code that has side-effects on my system.  Do you have `tight_boundingbox=True` in your `matplotlibrc`?

Comment: I am using the install default matplotlibrc which doesn't have anything set for tight_boundingbox, so if tight_boundingbox=True is the default then yes? I suspect that something like that is what is getting me.  I found that the nodes were being placed at the same coordinates, but that the bounding box didn't seem to be the same size.

Comment: I remembered the rcparam wrong, it is `savefig.bbox`.  The default is not tight.